# How to pass object between activities in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

While retrieving appSession I get a RunTimeException:

```
appSession = (ApplicationSession)intent.getParcelableExtra("appSession");
```

I am creating a app in which at the launch of app I create an ApplicationSession class object. I want to pass this object to all activities upon launch. How do I achieve this?

```
// app start
// contains data specific to app which I need to use across all activites.
ApplicationSession appSession = new ApplicationSession();
```

How to pass `appSession` to all activites?

Comment: Try the technique given here as an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data

Comment: you can get info from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: please learn how to properly format your questions, see  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `ApplicationSession` `implement` `Parcelable`, and when you are starting an `Activity` try something like:

```
ApplicationSession appSession = new ApplicationSession();
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivityName.class);
i.putExtra("appSession", appSession);
startActivity(i);
```

OR if it makes sense in your use case, just make `ApplicationSession` a static [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) class and let it live in a subclass of `Application` that you write.

Comment: hey thnx for the asnwer ... But i got a new issue... while retrieving it throws RunTimeException.. appSession = (ApplicationSession)intent.getParcelableExtra("appSession");

Comment: I can't make sense of that without a stack trace or message