# using singleton as a global cache for selected database values

Tags: android, database, singleton

I like to use a Singleton as a globally accessible cache for certain database values. This is my definition of the singleton with sample variables gi1, and gDBAdapter:

```
public class GlobalVars {
    private Integer gi1;
    private WebiDBAdapter gDBAdapter;

    private static GlobalVars instance = null;
       protected GlobalVars() {
          // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
       }
       public static GlobalVars getInstance() {
          if(instance == null) {
             instance = new GlobalVars();
          }

          //  now get the current data from the DB, 

          WebiDBAdapter myDBAdapter = new WebiDBAdapter(this);  // <- cannot use this in static context

          gDBAdapter = myDBAdapter;     // <- cannot use this in static context
          myDBAdapter.open();

          Cursor cursor = myDBAdapter.fetchMainEntry();
          startManagingCursor(cursor); // <- the method startManagingCursor is undefined for the type GlobalVars
          // if there is no DB yet, lets just create one with default data
            if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                cursor.close();
                createData();  // <- the method createData is undefined for the type GlobalVars
                cursor = myDBAdapter.fetchMainEntry();
                startManagingCursor(cursor);// <- the method startManagingCursor is undefined for the type GlobalVars
            }

            gi1 = cursor.getInt(cursor  // <- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field gi1
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(WebiDBAdapter.KEY1));
            if (gi1 == null) gi1 = 0;

            cursor.close();

          return instance;
       }
```

But all the references to the instance vars are not recognized.

All the `// <-` entries show the errors I get

I guess there is some basics that I am not doing right here.

What would be the right way to create the singleton and initialize its values with the values from the database?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data) class,

also there is no such thing as `this` in a static function

Comment: The problem with the application class is - as I read - I cannot rely on its values to exist throughout the livecycle of the app. I read that it might get killed when the app gets interrupted by a phone call and loose its values when it returns. Isn't this true?

Comment: I think the activity may be restarted, but the application context is not lost. [Read this if you want to store activity related info.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html). If at all you found that phone calls are disrupting your data, use the `PhoneStateListener` to detect them and handle it . The OS will only kill your application if there is a memory shortage during the phone call