# Get the position of a spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm trying to get the position (number) of the spinner when selected to use it in another Activity that will display a different map each time depending on the item selected. when I run the application it crashes. this is the first Activity code:

```
public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {
    public Spinner spinner1;
    public Integer number;
    private Button valideButton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MySpinner();
        valide_button();

    }

    public void MySpinner() {

        final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.num, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                                      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                // Object item = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                TestProjectActivity.this.number = spinner1
                        .getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {// do nothing
            }

        });

    }

    public void valide_button() {

        valideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valide_button);
        valideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(TestProjectActivity.this,
                        MetroMapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The way to get the selection of the spinner is:

```
  spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Documentation reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()

However, in your code, the one place you are referencing it is within your `setOnItemSelectedListener()`. It is not necessary to poll the spinner, because the `onItemSelected` method gets passed the position as the "position" variable.

So you could change that line to:

```
TestProjectActivity.this.number = position + 1;
```

If that does not fix the problem, please post the error message generated when your app crashes.

Comment: Already in the code, but when I try to use 'number' in another activity, it crashes

Comment: Try moving "number" into an application class. Activity variables are better off staying within the activity. Alternately, try setting number as a static member. read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4208886/602661

Comment: Briliant! I created an application class that will hold the data I will share between the 2 activities. Cheers man.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt = findViewById(R.id.button);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.sp_item);
        setInfo();
        spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this, arrayList);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);



        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //first,  we have to retrieve the item position as a string
                // then, we can change string value into integer
                String item_position = String.valueOf(position);

                int positonInt = Integer.valueOf(item_position);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "value is "+ positonInt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });







note: the position of items is counted from 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    final int[] positions=new int[2]; 
    Spinner sp=findViewByID(R.id.spinner);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText( arg2....);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (position ==0) {
    if (rYes.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(SportActivity.this, "yes ur answer is right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (rNo.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(SportActivity.this, "no.ur answer is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to select both check boxes.
Is there a  problem with it?