# Android: How to find spinner item from where it is comming

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi i have three items in the spinner, and based on the selected item i am making some calculation and showing the user . for 3 items i have 6 different calculations, i want to know **FROM** item and **To** item , so that i can take from value and to value and make the calculation. How to handle this scenario.

Below is simple switch case , but not solving my scenario

```
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) {
                        switch (position) 
                        {          
                            case 0:

                                  edt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                   edt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   edt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    qtyString = edt1.getText().toString();
                                   if(qtyString == null || qtyString.trim().equals("") || qtyString.trim().equals(".")){

                                   }else{
                                       float k = Float.parseFloat(qtyString);
                                       edt1.setText(removeTrailingZeros(poundTokilo(k))); 
                                   }
                                break;               

                            case 1:
                                 edt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                   edt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   edt3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                   if(edt1.getText().toString().equals("") || edt1.getText().toString().equals(".")){

                                   }else{
                                   float qtyString1 = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText().toString());
                                   edt1.setText(removeTrailingZeros(kiloTopound(qtyString1)));
                                   }
                                break;     

                            case 2:
                                edt1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                edt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                edt3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                if(edt1.getText().toString().equals("")){

                                   }else{      
                                float qtyString2 = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText().toString());
                                edt2.setText(removeTrailingZeros(kiloTostomepound(qtyString2).get(0).get(STONE)));
                                edt3.setText(removeTrailingZeros(kiloTostomepound(qtyString2).get(0).get(STONEPOUND)));
                                   }
                                break;     
                        } 

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597582/get-the-position-of-a-spinner-in-android

Answer (score 0):

`switch-case` not support rang based conditions so you can achieve same by using only one `break` in and `default` in `switch-case` :

```
switch (position) {
  case 1: case 2:case 3: 
     // executed when position is from 1 to 3
     break;
  default:
     // executed when position is not from 1 to 3
}
```

**OR**

Create a method which return `false` when  `position` is not between 1 to 3 and then use `if-else` ladder for execute code according to condition :

```
public boolean isNumInRange(int number, int from, int to) {
  return from <= number && number <= to;
}
```

Now call `isNumInRange(number,2,3)` to check number is present in given range

Comment: what if it starts from 2-->3 and 3-->2

Comment: @teekib: create a conman method with take three params position,from and to then return true false according to number. see my edit answer

Comment: Hi lets think i can go from 1--> 3 or 2-->3, so below will be the condition in case 3? if(isNumInRange(1, 1, 2)){      
                              }else {}

Comment: Hi lets think i can go from 1--> 3 or 2-->3, so below will be the condition in case 3? if(isNumInRange(3, 1, 3)){      
                              }else {}....the both (3, 1, 3) and (3, 2, 3) will be true right

Comment: i did as below if(isNumInRange(2, 0, 2)){      
                  System.out.println("printing kilo to stone pound");
                  
                 } else {
                  System.out.println("printing pound to stone pound");
                 
                  
                 }  but alaways printing the first loop only

Comment: since both (2, 0, 2) and (2, 1, 2)) are true so it is not going to else part?

Comment: @teekib: (2,0,2) is always return true because here `from <= number && number <= to;` we are also checking if number of equals to less then so change this condition

Comment: @teekib: change `number <= to` to `number < to`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68633/discussion-between-teekib-and--k).

Comment: @teekib modify `isNumInRange` method for changing range condition

Comment: i changed  number <= to to number < to but still bot working, please can u edit your answer