# getting data from first activity to fourth activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-edittext

i want to get text written in the EditText first activity and set that text to the another EditText which is fourth activity.

Comment: [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) will be the answer here.

Comment: u can set the value of the edittext in a global variable then acess it in the Fourth activity

Comment: See my updated answer and comment on your accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in your first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,Viewnotification.class);
          intent.putExtra("Value1", youredittextvalue.getText().toString());
startActiviy(intent);
```

And in your fourth Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
yourfourthactivityedittext.setText(value1);
```

Comment: Its not necessary that he will directly open fourth activity from first directly what is he opens Second and third activity in between and goes to fourth that time this will fail. :(

Comment: @ Rinalkumar But he has not declare in question as move from first-second-third-fourth activities.

Comment: But what if it happens so this should be generic solution which should work in any case :)

Answer (score 1):

1- use [SharedPreferences](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

2- set in [apllication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data) class

3- pass to using intent from 1-> 2 ->3 ->4

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do is,
You can assign one **static variable** which is public inside first activity like,

`public static String myEditTextContent;`

Set this after you set the value from your edit text like,

```
myEditTextContent = editText.getText().toString();
```

Use the same in fourth activity like

`FirstActivityClass.myEditTextContent` and set it in this(fourth) activity.

Later on you can use intent's **`putExtra,SQLLite Database,Shared Preference`** also, as suggested by others

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

First Use SharedPreferences  like

```
// declare
SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;


in On create

//initialize
                pref = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit = pref.edit();


// add data in it
edit.putString("USERNAME", EditText1.getText().toString());
edit.putString("PASSWORD", EditText1.getText().toString());
edit.putString("USERID",   Text1.getText().toString());

// save data in it
edit.commit();


to get data


// access it 

String passwrd = pref.getString("PASSWORD", "");
String userid = pref.getString("USERID", "");


And the second way

Send data from 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 and 3 to 4 activity 
with intents like

    Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Secondclass.class);
                    i.putExtra("userid", EditText1.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("username",EditText2.getText().toString());

                    startActivity(i);


and recieve in each activity like

       Intent i = getIntent();
     String   ursid = i.getStringExtra("userid");
 String   ursername = i.getStringExtra("username");
```