# Passing information to a new Activity from a class extending BaseAdapter

Tags: android

I've got following method in a class, which is a custom adapter for an ListView.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String test = availableDevices.get(position).getAddress().toString();   
        }
    });
```

The String `test` contains a mac-address of a device. My question is: How can I pass this variable to a new activity. It seems to me that I cant do it the usual way like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            startActivityForResult(**,**);
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243976/getting-data-from-first-activity-to-fourth-activity-in-android/11244047#11244047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED IT THIS WAY**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(c, Connection.class);
            intent.putExtra("mac", test);
            c.startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by passing the string in the intent like this:

```
intent.putExtra("Test", test);
```

Where the first parameter is a key, and the second is the value.
Then in the other activity do:

```
Intent launchingIntent = getIntent();  
launchingIntent.getStringExtra("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

pass test  as to new Activity2:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("Test", test);
startActivityForResult(intent,0); // 0 is as requestCode here
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Context object for classes other than those which extend Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(contextObj, Activity2.class);
           intent.putExtra("macadd", //value goes here);
           contextObj.startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode goes here);
```

Comment: I only got these error messages: The method setClass(Context, Class<?>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (DeviceAdapter, Class<Connection>) and The method startActivityForResult(DeviceAdapter, Class<Connection>) is undefined for the type Context

Answer (score 1):

set public static String test. then you able to access it hold application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the SharedPreferences like this

```
 String username = CarName.getText().toString();
         SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
         editor.putString("Shareusername",username);
         editor.commit();
```

and at the receiving end use something like this

//TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblnames);
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String shareUsername = settings .getString("Shareusername","null");
        Vehicle.setText(shareUsername);

Answer (score 0):

while setting adpater like  pass in it YourCurrentActivity.this

```
 Adapter adapter=new Adapter(YourCurrentActivity.this);
```

while in your ***Adpater*** class made changes as shown below

```
 public Activity activity;
 public Adapter(Activity act) {
    activity = act;    
 }
```

after this use code as shown below in your method

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(activity.this, Activity2.class);
  intent.putExtra("Test", test);
  startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```