# Pass parameter by reference using intent

Tags: android, reference

Using `itent.putExtra` makes a copy of my object. So changes make on this object on the activity that recive this itent does no reflect on others activity.

In my case will be good have reference to this object instead a copy, this is possible ?

ps: I know i can use `onActivityResult` to retrive the changes make on the object, but in my case the changes make on the object need to be done before the end of the activity.

Comment: Make it your object static

Answer (score 0):

Other way is: set a reference to a common property from activity1 (I am using MyApplication). The activity2 knows where to find that reference via a getter and it will use it. Decide if you want to modify the properties in activity2, when finished / every time you can have the reference in activity1.

This way is not needed to serialize / deserialize the object either. ( performance improvement too)

Answer (score 0):

You can just store a reference to the object in a static member variable, like this:

```
public class Globals {
     public static MyObject myObject;
}
```

Now, in the code that has the object, you just do:

```
Globals.myObject = object;
```

and in the new activity, you can get it like this:

```
doSomethingWith(Globals.myObject);
```

Now, having said that, you need to be aware of the following:

Android can kill your process if your application is in the background pretty much any time it wants to. When the user then returns to your application, Android will create a new process for your application and then it will **recreate only the activity that was on the top of the activity stack** (ie: the one that was showing). In that case, the newly created activity will not be able to get the iobject by accesing `Globals.myObject` because the process has been newly created and that member variable is null.

Comment: So to prevent the object to be lost when the app is on background i can create an static var on my activity to hold the value ?

like: holdThis = Globals.myObject;

Comment: This is not a great solution.  You should use the Application class for this (basically a global singleton accessible for anywhere in your Application)

Comment: @Booger: I have just provided my own view. The Application class is also a good solution, so as to share the data globally, but here you would also have memory leakage issues. data is shareable to the entire application.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj fair enough.  Your solution would work, but I think the standard solution would be the Application class.  You are right that the developer needs to be careful to manage memory (and get rid of stale data when necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Application class, which you can get a reference to using the getApplicationContext() method.

Bottom line, create an Application class, which you will be able to reference from any class in your App, then you can reference a variable that is local to that class.

Here is a good SO question about this:
[Using the Android Application class to persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data)