# IndexOutOfBoundsException for ArrayList in a Dialog - Android

Tags: java, android, dialog, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am populating an `ArrayList<Long>` in `QuestionView.java`.  I am passing it into `Results.java` and then calling that `ArrayList<Long>` in  a `dialog` in the `Results.java` class.

Let me know if that didn't make sense I will try to clarify further.  All code and LogCat output is below.  Thank you in advance!

QuestionView.java

```
public class QuestionView extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Long> pointsPerQuestion = new ArrayList<Long>(10);

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }

public ArrayList<Long> getPointsPerQuestion() {
    return pointsPerQuestion;
}

public void nextQuestion() {
    pointsPerQuestion.add(points); 
    score = score + points;
    i++;
    loadQuestion();
}

public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {     
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        bar.setProgress((int) millisUntilFinished);
        points = (millisUntilFinished / 100) / 2;
        timeremaining.setText("Points remaining: " + points);
        if(i < 10) {
            questionNumber.setText("Question " + (i + 1) + " of 10");
        }
    }
```

Results.java

```
public class Results extends Activity {

QuestionView qv = new QuestionView();

ArrayList<Question> queryList = qv.getQueries();
ArrayList<Question> qs;
ArrayList<Long> pointsPerQuestion;
ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>(10);

final Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resultsmain);

    qs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");

    pointsPerQuestion = qv.getPointsPerQuestion();

    q1details.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.q1details);
            dialog.setTitle("Question 1 Details");

            ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            TextView question = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.question);
            TextView selectedAnswer = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.selectedAnswer);
            TextView correctAnswer = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.correctAnswer);
            TextView points = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.points);
            TextView verse = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.verse);
            Button close = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

            if(qs.get(0).getSelectedAnswer() == qs.get(1).getCorrectAnswer()) {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_check_mark);
            } else {
                image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_x);
            }

            question.setText(qs.get(0).getQuery());
            selectedAnswer.setText("" + qs.get(0).getSelectedAnswer());
            correctAnswer.setText("" + qs.get(0).getCorrectAnswer());
            points.setText("" + pointsPerQuestion.get(0));    //Line 120
            verse.setText(qs.get(0).getVerse());        
            close.setText("Close");

            close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

LogCat output

```
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at matt.lyons.bibletrivia.Results$4.onClick(Results.java:120)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 15:21:13.281: E/AndroidRuntime(1519):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**

Even when I put this line of code:

```
long x = 666;
        pointsPerQuestion.add(x);
```

in my `onCreate()` method, I get the same error.  Could possibly my `getPointsPerQuestion()` method in the `QuestionView` class not be working?

Comment: Show the code where you start the Results activity

Comment: you're trying to get information from a list, that there isn't any thing added so far, try getting the info after the method nextQuestion() been called.

Comment: Where is the "pointsPerQuestion" variable being populated?

Comment: How do you initialize pointsPerQuestion in QuestionView? This list is empty when you access it

Comment: i guess error is in `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries")`. Check the output of this function probably its creating an empty list.

Comment: @user1866707, the code where you call startActivity in QuestionView

Comment: @baraky - I edited my post showing ````pointsPerQuestion```` being initialized.  @SuKu - the ArrayList<Question> named ````queries```` is fully functional and not a problem.

Comment: ` qv.getPointsPerQuestion()` seams to return an empty array. Use a debugger or print it to console for debugging.

Comment: Looks like you never add anything to pointsPerQuestion list

Comment: From the ````OutOfBoundsException```` it does seem that the ArrayList is empty.  But I know for a fact ````nextQuestion()```` is being called but just not sure why the ````pointsPerQuestion.add(points);```` is not adding elements to the ArrayList.

Comment: Please see my edit to the original post.  And why did I get a downvote for this question?  :(

Comment: As SuKu said, it seems the problem is at "qs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("queries");" You need to verify if qs is different from null to use it further (it seems it is crashing here: qs.get(0).getSelectedAnswer())... Check the part where you call the intent which gets you into Results activity, to verify if you are putting the arraylistextra as it should be

Comment: If I comment out ````points.setText("" + pointsPerQuestion.get(0));    //Line 120```` the whole program works correctly so the line @offcourse and @SuKu are referring to is not an issue.

Comment: I am not passing the ````pointsPerQuestion```` arraylist through intent.  I have a getter method for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a new instance of the QuestionView class:

```
QuestionView qv = new QuestionView();
```

which you're then using to get the pointsPerQuestion array:

```
pointsPerQuestion = qv.getPointsPerQuestion();
```

So, whatever processing you previously did in the QuestionView activitiy is now gone when you're in the Result activity.
You could make the array public and static (in QuestionView) but i'd advice against it.

Better to take a look at this thread: [Using the Android Application class to persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data)

and pick one of the solutions from there.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha.  Exactly the answer I was looking for.  Thank you for the link and I will integrate one of the suggestions.