# maintaining username throughout my android app

Tags: android

I am creating a simple login app. Which will display username after logged when  successful .Here, I am sending username from `Login Page` to `Second Page` through intent as follows

```
String sendusername=results;
            Intent inte=new Intent(Login.this,SubmitActivity.class);
            inte.putExtra("displayusername", sendusername);
            startActivity(inte);
```

receiving that intent in the second page as follows:

```
Intent inte=getIntent();
    final String Username=inte.getStringExtra("displayusername");
```

I am showing this value in a `TextView`.But, the problem here is once after moving to the forward pages when I went back to the second page, it is showing `null` value in place of username. Any one is there to give me a idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using SharedPreferences.  This is the closest thing to global data in an Android app.

To save useername:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrivateData",
    PreferenceActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.commit();
```

And to read username:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrivateData",
    PreferenceActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
username = prefs.getString("username", null);  // where null is the default
```

And make sure you clear this setting when your app first starts.

Comment: thanq EJk.but it is asking me to create context variable..any idea

Comment: Yes, this is a reference to an android.content.Context.  Activities are  Contexts, so you can pass the current activity, (i.e. "this").  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 0):

After logging in you can save the username in shared preference and when ever you want you can get the username.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for me is using an Application class.

See the android documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

And check out this post:

[Using the Android Application class to persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data)

As you need more variables you can simply add them to this class and basically use them from wherever you want.