# Upgrade rows on app upgrade only

Tags: android, android-sqlite

If I want to update DB rows only once only when my users upgrade their app, then would you do it in the OnUpgrade method in my DB handler class  or would you do it as an asyncTask in the Application class based on SharedPreferences?

Thank you

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()` is called when the *database* version changes, not when the *application* version changes. These are only equivalent if each new version of your app also increases the database version used in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor, which usually isn't the case.

Comment: Oh I should've clarified more. I am changing the DB version in this case

Comment: In that case, definitely do this in `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical design pattern for database updates in an app goes something like the code below and every time you update your application where a database change is required, you bump the database version used in your SQLiteOpenHelper-derived class.

This, of course, presumes you used SQLiteOpenHelper to manage getting a reference to your SQLite DB in your provider:

```
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    if (oldVersion == 1) {
                // DO WORK TO UPGRADE FROM VERSION 1 to 2
                oldVersion += 1;
    }

    if (oldVersion == 2) {
                // DO WORK TO UPGRADE FROM VERSION 2 to 3
                oldVersion += 1;
    }

    if (oldVersion == 3) {
                // DO WORK TO UPGRADE FROM VERSION 3 to 4
                oldVersion += 1;
    }
}
```

This allows any user to upgrade from any previous version to the current version and ensures all the changes are made in the right order.  So, it would only be done once, because on the next version, the database version becomes higher.

Comment: I have this code going an I typically use to create new tables. So I guess you are suggesting to even use to to update tables better than the using shared preferences

Comment: Absolutely. Unless you are in a very controlled environment, you should always ensure any version of an app can be upgraded to any subsequent version.  This technique will always perform the database operations necessary to bring the app up-to-date in sequence.