# How to bypass intent extras in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know if there is a way to pass all the extras to the new intent.

Is it possible? And is it a good idea?

The reason is that I want to save the login state as a json string, and pass it in between Activities. I don't want to store data with SQLite or anything. Can I bypass all the intent extras to the new intent ?

Comment: why you dont save into shared preference?

Comment: @Shayan I don't know how to :) I will look for it. Does it require SD Card or Database ?

Comment: you can use global class also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please consider Shared Preference :

```
  // Declaration
   public static String KEY = "SESSION";

   public static void saveUserName(String username, Context context) {
        Editor editor = context
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("username", username);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return savedSession.getString("username", "");
    }
```

You can store the login credentials to preference and retrieve them as well in any of your activity.

```
SaveUsername("Your text to save", Your_activity.this);
```

And to retrieve the value

```
String mUserName = getUserName(YourActivity.this);
```

It is recommended to have all your preference methods in your utils class to keep the code organized.

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Thanks! This looks like exactly what I need. and one question: when does this session get deleted? When the application is closed ? or, sleep? or uninstall?

Comment: Case 1 :When you click Settings --> Application --> Manage application --> Your Application --> Clear Data  Case 2 : Unistall the app. The preference values remains even if you exit from the application.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use Shared Preference to save the Login session of user here is handy example of managing session using shared preference **http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/** I used it earlier and suggest you to have a look at it.

Comment: using #adb shell pull  I wouldn't get your credentials stored like plain text ?

Answer (score 0):

Any of the two may help you.

1. Saving it in the [sharedPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/2219600) file.
2. If you want them to be accessable throught the application you can use the [applicationClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data), like a global singleton.