# Error on Geofencing event when I use putExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice, geofencing

I'm having trouble trying to pass an object to the GeofenceTransitionIntentService. Whenever I use putExtra(), the geofenceTransition is -1 so I always get an error and the rest of the code is skipped. If I don't use putExtra(), the notification does work.
Is there any way to solve this?

This is the piece of code where i want to put the extras, currentCharacter is a Character and does implement serializable.

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (geofencePendingIntent != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "getGeofencependingintent return");
        return geofencePendingIntent;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("char", currentCharacter);
    Log.d(TAG, "getGeofencependingintent new");
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Here is the piece of code where it goes wrong. This is in a class that extends IntentService

```
 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent); 
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = "err";
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
        List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                this,
                geofenceTransition,
                triggeringGeofences
        );

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
        Log.d(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, "error");
    }
  currentCharacter = intent.getSerializableExtra("char");

}
```

Comment: what is the type of `currentCharacter`?

Comment: currentCharacter is a Character and does implement serializable.

Comment: ohh sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: I have no problems whatsoever passing it to other classes or activities it's just this one

Comment: Did you try getting getting error code from event?

Comment: Also, did you try getting `char` from `intent` in `onHandleIntent`

Comment: After some debugging I figured out that geofencingEvent didn't have an error but the geofence transition is -1, this has to be 1

Comment: And to answer your question : yes I did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134077/discussion-between-nick-bleyen-and-kalpesh-patel).

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558550/can-i-get-data-from-shared-preferences-inside-a-service) to share data between an intent and a service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by converting the object to a Json string and passing it like that.
In the intentservice, I created a new object from the Json string.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the problem by using "Shared Preference's" instead of the intent.putExtra();. Here's a link to another StackOverflow question.
[How to bypass intent extras in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811518/how-to-bypass-intent-extras-in-android) The accepted answer explains how to use it.

**Edit:** here's another source for handling "Shared Preference's"
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html