# Can I use a public static object as shared var among Activity?

Tags: android

I want to fill in all properties of object myRule based class MRule, I create a several activities to do it, 
an Activity to pass name and enabled, an Activity  to pass onlyNumberList, exceptNumberList, etc...
and use Back and Next button to switch different Activity.

Because Intent.putExtra can't pass object, so I plan to create a public static object staticMRule as shared var among with activities, is it OK?

And , is there the more better way?

```
Public static  MRule  staticMRule; 



public class MRule {
    public int ruleID;
    public String name;
    public Boolean enabled;
    public IncomingType incomingType;
    public List<String> onlyNumberList;
    public List<String> exceptNumberList;
    public List<String> receiverNumberList;  //短信转发到的号码

    public MRule(){ 
        onlyNumberList=new ArrayList<String>();
        exceptNumberList=new ArrayList<String>();
        receiverNumberList=new ArrayList<String>();
    }   
}


public class activity1  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);       

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  staticMRule.name="a"; 
            }
        }); 

    }
}

public class activity2  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);       

        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  staticMRule.enabled=false;
            }
        }); 

    }
}
```

Comment: use application class

Comment: Thanks! Could you show some sample code?

Comment: Go thru this link: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/

Comment: Just some heads up, you CAN share object via Intent. only thing is that the object has to implement `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Application Class

`Application` class is the base class where you can maintain *global variables*. One can override Application class by extending his own class from it and specifying that class in `AndroidManifest.xml`’s tag.

`Application` class exists through out the app life cycle. Creating a static singletons can serve the purpose instead of extending and overriding Application class.

Following code you can use

```
public class YourApplication extends Application 
{     
     private int result = 0;

     public int getResult() {
          return result;
     }

     public void setResult(int result) {
         this.result= result;
     }
}
```

To access it,

```
YourApplication app = ((YourApplication)this.getApplication());
app.setResult(100);
//...
int result = app.getResult();
```

**References**

- http://mobisoftinfotech.com/android-application-class-example-a-brief-tutorial-on-android-application-class/
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html
- [Using the Android Application class to persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data)
- http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: Thanks! What are different between Application and public static var

Answer (score 0):

You can make class which implements parcelable and then you can easily pass Object of that class by using Intent.putExtra(key,ObjOfYourParcelableClass)

Answer (score 0):

Another option that is more elegant is to use an injection framework with a singleton. Have a look at [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) or [Dagger](https://github.com/square/dagger).