# How can I pass a LocationClient through an intent and when the abstract methods are present in the main activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

```
LocationClient(Context context,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks connectionCallbacks, 
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener connectionFailedListener)
```

This is usually called as:

```
LocationClient LC = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

The problem with this is that it treats the current activity as the context, and `ConnectionCallbacks` and `OnConnectionFailedListener` require abstract methods. I want to be able to create this client in my main activity, then pass it to one of various other activities that the user can go to. Am I able to pass this as a parcelable in an intent? What will happen to the abstract methods created in the main activity? Is there a standard for doing this or do you know of any better ways to handle this, or does it make more sense just to make a new LocationClient in each activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocationClient` is not Parcelable so you cannot pass it through an intent.

Typically you only want or need one LocationClient per application, not per activity, so I wouldn't create one in each activity.

That leaves you with the option to create it in your Application class. The Application also derives from `Context` so this should not present any problem.

You can read about deriving your own Application class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data) or elsewhere.