# How to pass large json string to next activity

Tags: android, json

I am sending large JSON string where records of `JSON` array length is 800 but currently when I start that `Activity` then application quits without any crash message but when I reduced the records to 100 then it works perfectly.

I am doing like below

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
        ActivityName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("jsondata", respUserData);
getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(myIntent,
        pick_plan);
getActivity().overridePendingTransition(
        R.anim.lefttorightanim, R.anim.righttoleftanim);
```

So what it is correct way to send large `JSON` to next `Activity` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a Bundle to store the data (and attach it to the intent) instead of directly adding data to the intent?

Comment: @Chnoch No I didn't try but let me know does `Bundle` can store large `JSON` ?

Comment: Do you have a sample of your JSONObject available? It should be able to store large amounts of data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can pass values as you mentioned. It will be as a bundle so it can hold large amount of data also.
We can pass Arraylist, model classes etc using the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass large String or Large Data directly in to intent, you have to use `Application Class`.
Set variables and methods in application class.
To get more information about `Application Class` view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's probably not a global state that you pass, I advise against using the `Application Class`. If it is data that you use all the time you can easily store it there.

For passing a large amount of data using the provided way with `putExtra()` should work fine. Apparently the `Bundle` doesn't handle your JSONObject correctly. You can try to convert it to a String, pass this to the `Intent.putExtra()` and then reconstruct the JSONObject from the String. This will have some impact on the performance, but should be usable as a workaround.

Comment: Yes I am doing same, converted `JSONObject` to `String` but have same problem. So Should I use `Bundle` instead of `Intent.putExtra` to pass large `JSON` string ?

Comment: No, you should be able to use Intent.putExtra() directly, as it also works with Bundles in the background.