# Passing ImageView from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I have been trying to create an android app with the integration of Adobe creative SDJ but I have encountered some problems.

I have created an Activity where one launches camera or gallery to select an image for editing it. The camera launches and the photo is captured and saved in this path:

`storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myAppName/myImage.jpg`

It is also supposed to be displayed in an `ImageView` in the same activity but it isn't being displayed. In another activity, I have integrated the ImageEditing UI of the creative sdk from Adobe which needs an `imageUri` as an input image.

Here are my codes for displaying Image in the `ImageView`:

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        // camera codes 
        String path = "storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Touch/touch.jpg";
        resultImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

        // gallery codes
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            resultImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
```

How can I convert the `ImageView` into Uri and send it to the next activity? Thanks in advance!

Comment: show your code how you are displaying image in ImageView

Comment: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // camera codes
        String path = "storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Touch/touch.jpg";
        resultImageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

        // gallery codes
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            resultImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

Comment: Curve, image is visible in ImageView or not?

Comment: and also send `imageUri ` to next Activity for accessing same image

Comment: the image when selected from gallery is visible but not when captured from camera

Comment: You may want to look at using a fragment. I think it would be easier to do this than two activities, My two cents, still not worth two cents :)

Comment: @MNM  thanks for the comment..would i get a hint of codes for using in fragment..

Comment: give this a shot http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm I have not used fragments personally but I have seen them used and that look pretty good for what your are doing

Comment: also I found this for you too it may help give you another option on what to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data

Comment: Are you giving hardcoded path to Image clicked by camera..????

Comment: @prakshi yes I am giving a hardcoded path

Comment: @MNM  thanks for link..will see to it..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong for camera code. as you say your gallery code is working fine .try this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try{
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 0) {
                //taking clicked image from Intent of activity
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");//storing image 

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
 //adding clicked image to ImageView
 imgClicked.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

Hope this will help you..:-)

Comment: Thanks! Will try this