# Best way to save an string in Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences

I want to save the ID of the user that I pass from PHP then I put it in a *putExtra* of an intent to move the string to my HomeActivity. 
To have a fast access, protected to see by the user and to access to in all activities, what do you recommend to use?

Comment: use [SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

Comment: @Roger RV i recommend you use shared preferences and clear them once user logs out

Comment: If you use it really frequently, you may store it in an Application object. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data

Comment: @PEMapModder Thanks I'll see it and *SharedPreferences*

Comment: @RogerRV note that it is different from SharedPreferences. SharedPreferences is for storing data _in the harddisk (or SD card)_, while using an Application field is just a way to cache it in memory temporarily. If you want to use this method to keep a user always logged in in your app, you should use both, and a lazy-getter for your Application field.