# Pass data from activity with retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, retrofit2

i'm create recycler view to display data, after that I want to pass 
position of the data to the another activity, but when I use the `loge` for check if position is pass or not I can't found the position in `logcat`.

In MainActivity I add static list for Recipe model and I create method to return this list:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<Model> list;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private static List<Recipe>mListrecipe;

    String url = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        /// create a list--
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        ///  get the list from json file
                getRetrofitArray();

        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter( list, MainActivity.this);
            // set adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

        public void getRetrofitArray(){

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                .baseUrl(url)
                                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                .build();

            RetrofitArrayAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayAPI.class);
            Call<List<Recipe>>  call = service.getRecipeDetails();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Recipe>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Response<List<Recipe>> response) {
                    Log.e("main ", " retrofit response "+ response.body().toString());
                    mListrecipe=response.body();
                    for (int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++){
                        Log.e("main ", " name "+ response.body().get(i).getName() + " serving "+
                           response.body().get(i).getServings());
                        list.add( new Model( Model.IMAGE_TYPE,response.body(), response.body().get(i).getName() ,
                               " Serving " +response.body().get(i).getServings() )  );

                    }
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Recipe>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("main ", " retrofit error "+ t.toString());
                }
            });



        }

public static List<Recipe>getList(){
    return mListrecipe;
}
}
```

> I add putExtra with key value to pass position

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList<Model> dataset;
    private Context mContext;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Model> mlist, Context context) {
        this.dataset = mlist;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

          ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, subtitle;
        public ImageTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.title = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.subtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            this.imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);


        }
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist, parent, false);
        return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
       Model object = dataset.get(position);

        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setText( object.title );
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setText( object.subtitle );
        /// dataset.get(position)
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,SelectReceipe.class);
                intent.putExtra("itempostion",position);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).subtitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,SelectReceipe.class);
                intent.putExtra("itempostion",position);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ( (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,SelectReceipe.class);
                intent.putExtra("itempostion",position);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.size() ;
    }
}
```

this is 2 activity I pass position but i can't find value in `logcat`

```
public class SelectReceipe extends AppCompatActivity {        
    List<Recipe>sListRecipe;
    public int itempostion;
    private String TAG;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectreceipe);

        sListRecipe=MainActivity.getList();
        Intent i =getIntent();
        itempostion= i.getExtras().getInt("itempostion");
        Log.e(TAG,"itempostion"+String.valueOf(itempostion)+"valou"+sListRecipe.get(itempostion).getName().toString());

    }
```

logcat:

```
 09-26 13:34:41.355 31852-31852/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
    09-26 13:34:42.459 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
    09-26 13:34:42.471 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20343: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
    09-26 13:34:42.471 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20345: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 20349: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    09-26 13:34:42.479 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.483 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    09-26 13:34:42.495 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 478: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    09-26 13:34:42.495 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.495 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    09-26 13:34:42.495 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 500: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    09-26 13:34:42.495 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
    09-26 13:34:42.695 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
    09-26 13:34:42.695 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 20822: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    09-26 13:34:42.699 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.735 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
    09-26 13:34:42.735 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 20233: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
    09-26 13:34:42.735 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
    09-26 13:34:42.739 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
    09-26 13:34:42.743 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 292: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    09-26 13:34:42.743 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    09-26 13:34:42.763 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    09-26 13:34:42.763 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    09-26 13:34:42.763 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.763 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    09-26 13:34:42.767 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 443: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    09-26 13:34:42.767 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    09-26 13:34:42.771 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    09-26 13:34:42.771 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 142 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
    09-26 13:34:42.771 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
    09-26 13:34:42.815 31852-31853/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 256K, 3% free 10939K/11271K, paused 18ms+1ms, total 27ms
    09-26 13:34:42.815 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
    09-26 13:34:42.911 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so

                                                                          [ 09-26 13:34:42.931 31852:31852 D/         ]
                                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7f81e90, tid 31852
    09-26 13:34:43.019 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
    09-26 13:34:43.035 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
    09-26 13:34:43.111 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-26 13:34:43.127 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    09-26 13:34:43.183 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7fa1438): name, size, mSize = 1, 4096, 4096
    09-26 13:34:43.339 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 22787: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips I/dalvikvm: Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 22786: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
    09-26 13:34:43.343 31852-31877/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
    09-26 13:34:43.567 31852-31853/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 279K, 4% free 11121K/11527K, paused 24ms+10ms, total 38ms
    09-26 13:34:44.079 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/main:  retrofit response [blueappsoftware.mybakingtips.Recipe@536b4c20, blueappsoftware.mybakingtips.Recipe@536c68ec, blueappsoftware.mybakingtips.Recipe@536c1a24, blueappsoftware.mybakingtips.Recipe@536e27b8]
    09-26 13:34:44.079 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/main:  name Nutella Pie serving 8
    09-26 13:34:44.079 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/main:  name Brownies serving 8
    09-26 13:34:44.079 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/main:  name Yellow Cake serving 8
    09-26 13:34:44.079 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/main:  name Cheesecake serving 8
    09-26 13:34:44.119 31852-31853/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 217K, 4% free 11298K/11655K, paused 15ms+0ms, total 20ms
    09-26 13:34:44.179 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7f36950): name, size, mSize = 9, 33856, 37952
    09-26 13:34:48.955 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    09-26 13:34:48.955 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    09-26 13:34:48.967 31852-31852/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    09-26 13:52:03.367 31852-31853/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 4% free 11375K/11847K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 16ms
    09-26 14:16:49.627 31852-31853/blueappsoftware.mybakingtips D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 426K, 5% free 11345K/11911K, paused 9ms+0ms, total 9ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not getting the list because you are using the getter from a different Activity.Instead, you can pass your list via Intent, but for that, you should implement your class as Parcelable or Serializable .Here is a nice post for that [How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-parcelable) And one thing if you are bound to load and temporarily save a list so that you can use anywhere in App then you can use setter and getter in Android Application class.Here is a nice post for that [Using the Android Application class to persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208886/using-the-android-application-class-to-persist-data)